# How to get device placement in eager mode?

Tags: python, tensorflow

When using graphs, we can log device placement of tensorflow operations via an argument of `Session`:

```
tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
```

However, in eager mode, there is no `Session`. How can we know the device placement of an operation when executing eagerly?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clearly advertised in the doc yet, but in eager mode, each `Tensor` and `Variable` has a `device` field which shows where a variable is located or where an operation took place.

However AFAIK there is no automatic device placement log that would trigger whenever an operation is run. So it may take some work to get device placements of operations that occur within a hierarchy of objects.